# How to add a button inside each DevExtreme PivotGrid cells using Angular2

Tags: angular, devextreme

I want to add a button inside each DevExtreme PivotGrid cells using Angular2.
It is possible to do achieve the same using jQuery like this:

[dxPivotGrid - How to add a button to the description cell](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T379176)

Answer (score 0):

The [cellPrepared](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxPivotGrid/Events/#cellPrepared) event helps you to achieve the behavior you described:

**Html**:

```
<dx-pivot-grid
    ...
    (onCellPrepared)="cellPrepared($event)">
```

**TS**:

```
cellPrepared(e) {
    $("<div>").dxButton({text: "Hello"}).appendTo(e.cellElement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, that's exactly how I didn't want to use it as it is using jQuery. I guess DevExtreme doesn't support adding a button using 'dxTemplate' in 'dx-pivot-grid' just like in 'dx-data-grid' but I have to live with this right now.